# Layouts problems

Tags: android, xml

Ребята,проблема заключается в том,что у меня один `LinerLayout` накрывает второй.
Я сделал один `LinerLayout` как шапку, а остальное свободное место хочу занять вторым `LinerLayout`, в котором будет находиться информация различная.
Уже не знаю что делать...

xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="by.ittech.test_chat.Profile">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы после окончания первого `Layout` начинался второй,а не так как сейчас,что второй накрывает первый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема кроется в родительском `FrameLayout`. Для решения вашей проблемы замените `FrameLayout`.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="by.ittech.test_chat.Profile">
```

на `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orintation="vertical"
        tools:context="by.ittech.test_chat.Profile">
```

Comment: Я использую данный Layout для фрагмента. Если я изменю, то это повлияет на работу фрагмента или нет?

Comment: @shcherbuk, нет, разметка не может повлиять на работу фрагмента, только на его отображение. В данном случае ни на работу, ни на отображение изменение типа `Layout` никак не повлияет.